# Cocoa: Extracting "A" from "Æ"

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I have a bunch of NSStrings from which I would like to grab the first character of and match them up in the range A-Z and # as a catch all for things that don't apply.

Different graphemes (I believe that's the correct word after some wiki'ing) have been giving me trouble. For example, I would like to extract A from "Æ".

I have taken a look at CFStringTransform, normalize and fold but none of had the desired effect.

Is there a reliable way of doing this? All the strings I'm working with are UTF8 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Æ cannot be broken down into components. It is not a compound glyph of A+E, but is a separate glyph. Compound glyphs are things like a+`

Answer (score 1):

The thing about "Æ" is that it is an ascii character in itself. Not a combination of two different characters so you can't extract the A from it because it is only 1 Character.

Edit:

Although you could perform a check to see if the String equals "Æ" and if it does tell it to switch it with "A" or convert it to its dec, form and subtract 81 which would give you an "A".

Comment: I know it's technically one character but with some of the other really cool stuff CFStringTransform can do, I was hoping this would be something it would know about. For example, the music app on iPhone handles this fine for the album named "Ænema" by Tool. It correctly places it under the A header in the table view.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want to get rid of all æ?

This should work if you do.

```
NSString *string = @"Æaæbcdef";
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"æ" withString:@"a"];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Æ" withString:@"A"];
```

### Edit

Rereading, you only seem to want the first character:

```
NSString *string = @"Æaæbcdef";
NSString *firstChar = [string substringToIndex:1];
firstChar = [firstChar stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"æ" withString:@"a"];
firstChar = [firstChar stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Æ" withString:@"A"];

NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", firstChar, [string substringFromIndex:1]];
```

Comment: That would work but I would like a more general solution. Æ is one of many characters I would like to deal with.